# Android app won't start noClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, error-handling, android-emulator, logcat, acra

I'm creating a gps app for the android! And now I've stumbled upon a problem. The app doesn't start at all... Any ideas of how to fix this?

```
04-05 12:54:50.877: D/dalvikvm(540): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
04-05 12:54:51.018: I/dalvikvm(540): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 5...
04-05 12:54:51.417: I/dalvikvm(540): Could not find method org.acra.ACRA.init, referenced from method com.kulplex.gaia.GaiaApp.onCreate
04-05 12:54:51.417: W/dalvikvm(540): VFY: unable to resolve static method 652: Lorg/acra/ACRA;.init (Landroid/app/Application;)V
04-05 12:54:51.417: D/dalvikvm(540): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
04-05 12:54:51.457: D/AndroidRuntime(540): Shutting down VM
04-05 12:54:51.457: W/dalvikvm(540): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
04-05 12:54:51.477: E/AndroidRuntime(540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 12:54:51.477: E/AndroidRuntime(540): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.acra.ACRA
04-05 12:54:51.477: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.kulplex.gaia.GaiaApp.onCreate(GaiaApp.java:54)
04-05 12:54:51.477: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
04-05 12:54:51.477: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3954)
04-05 12:54:51.477: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-05 12:54:51.477: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
04-05 12:54:51.477: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 12:54:51.477: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-05 12:54:51.477: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-05 12:54:51.477: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 12:54:51.477: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-05 12:54:51.477: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-05 12:54:51.477: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-05 12:54:51.477: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you need to post code for us to narrow down what the problem could be.

Comment: you should post your code but for what I could see in your errors, you are using a mapview and threads, and as far as I know there are issues regarding threads and mapviews since it "seems" that mapviews should be handled in the main thread.

Comment: great posting your error log wont solve your issue. what about code?///

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you've recently updated to [ADT 17](http://tools.android.com/download) and above, they've changed the `lib` library handling.

so you need to rename your `lib` dir to `libs`, 
then right click your project > properties > Java build path > Libraries > select all the jars with error markings on them and click `remove` > click `add JARs` > select all jars from your new `libs` dir.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 22):

I had this same issue after updating to the latest Android tools.

In the project properties, Java Build Path, Order and Export section, I had to make sure the Android Private Libraries was checked.

Then I had to clean the project. After that it seems to work.

> It was indeed an issue with 'Order and Export' of the Java Build Path.
>
> When upgrading, the 'Order and Export' of the new 'Android Private Libraries' is not always checked. And the android-support-v4.jar is now in this 'Android Private Libraries' section.
>
> To fix this, go to 'Order and Export' and check 'Android Private Libraries'. Then refresh/clean/rebuild.
>
> After you done this 'fix' for a library project, you may need to just close and re-open any depending project, because they may not see this 'fix' immediately.

I found the answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/adt-dev/epOfZbKPFdk).

Comment: This was fooling me with *ACRA 4.5* and the newest android sdk tools 22, build tools 17. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Same here, after updating to SDK Tools 22 and Build Tools 17 I had to tick the checkbox for `Android Private Libraries` in the `Order and Export` tab.